# Is there a way to serve mock data to a Vue.js application with the dev server?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, stubbing

I'm working on a Vue.js application that retrieves some data with ajax calls; in the dev environment I'm playing with the application in the browser using the builtin server and mocking the external resources with an [API stubber](https://github.com/contactlab/saray) that runs on its own server. Since both pieces of software are using node I'm wondering if there's a way to run both with a single command, serving the Vue.js application code and some static files for the mocked calls (which are not all GETs and require parameters, so sticking the json files in the app `public` folder wouldn't work).

**Edit**: let me try to clarify. The Vue.js application will interact with a backend service that is still being developed. On my workstation I can play with the application by just running the `npm run serve` command, but since there's no backend service I won't be able to try the most interesting bits. Right now I'm running [saray](https://github.com/contactlab/saray) alongside my application, serving some static json files that mock the server responses. It works fine but I'm effectively running two separate http servers, and since I'm new to the whole Vue, npm & javascript ecosystem, I was wondering if there's a better way, for instance serving the mock responses from the same (dev) server that's serving the Vue application.

Comment: are you looking for 2-way-data-binding with the sever? you want your data to get updated from both sides? in that case you might want to take a look at https://socket.io/ lib

Comment: Are you talking about using a template engine? like what express-generator provides?

Comment: I would [configure a `devServer.proxy`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy) to forward API requests to the mock server, and update an NPM script to start both the mock server and and dev server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could configure fake/mock responses from the dev server itself, by editing the *vue.config.js* file like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...

  devServer: {
    setup: function (app) {
     // For example, to define custom handlers for some paths:
      app.get('/icecreams', function (req, res) {
        res.json(someIceCreams(req, res))
      })
      
      ...
```

Such responses would be served by the devserver using HTTP, just like requests performed from the application to real API in production mode.

See also: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/